# Change color of UIBezierPath in Swift

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, swift2

I am working on a form of design project. In this project, you select an object and can change the color or size, or move.

Started a prototype of the app.

I will use `UIBezierPath` to draw the ways of the shapes, and will use `CAShapeLayer` to add to a sublayer of `UIView`.

This code draw one shape for example:

```
let insetRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: insetRect, cornerRadius: 30)
UIColor.redColor().setFill()
path.fill()

path.lineWidth = 100
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
path.stroke()

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

When the app starts, the shape is created without problems.

**I wish I could click on the screen and automatically change the color (random) from shape**.

Another problem: **The shapes are random, and they rectangle, ellipse, rounded square**. And due to these forms, I can not directly create on a `View` (reason for use the `UIBezierPath`).

Some can help me? I am trying to solve this for a few hours, and so far, found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding bezierPath as sub layer, you can use a custom view. Pass a bezier path coordinates and color to the view. Keep instance of bezier path at class level and draw in `DrawRect:` method.

When user touches view in controller, pass custom view message to change color and redraw it.

You can simply change bezier path color by using:

```
yourColor.setStroke();
```

You can force your view to redraw bezier with changed color using:

```
customView.setNeedsDisplay();
```

**EDIT**

**CustomView.m**

```
-(id) initWithPath:(UIBezierPath *) path color:(UIColor *) color
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        bezierPath = path;
        pathColor = color;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [bezierPath stroke];
}
```

In controller, you can initialize as,

```
CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithPath:yourBezierPath color:[UIColor redColor];
customView.frame = yourFrame;
[self.view addSubview:customView];
```

To change color,

```
[customView setPathColor:[UIColor greenColor];
[customView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @James I have posted sample code for objective c to give u an idea